# Why is MongoDB not using the compound index for the query?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

Here are the compound index and single index I have for this Collection:

```
///db.Collection.getIndexes()
/* 1 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "service.Collection"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "FirstId" : 1,
        "SecondId" : 1,
        "CreationTime" : -1
    },
    "name" : "FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime",
    "collation" : {
        "locale" : "en",
        "caseLevel" : false,
        "caseFirst" : "off",
        "strength" : 1,
        "numericOrdering" : false,
        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
        "maxVariable" : "punct",
        "normalization" : false,
        "backwards" : false,
        "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "ns" : "service.Collection"
},

/* 3 */
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "CreationTime" : 1
    },
    "name" : "CreationTime",
    "collation" : {
        "locale" : "en",
        "caseLevel" : false,
        "caseFirst" : "off",
        "strength" : 1,
        "numericOrdering" : false,
        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
        "maxVariable" : "punct",
        "normalization" : false,
        "backwards" : false,
        "version" : "57.1"
    },
    "ns" : "service.Collection"
}
```

The expected result is an IXSCAN using the `FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime` index:

```
///service.Collection.find({ FirstId: "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349", ///SecondId: "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f" })
///   .projection({})
///   .sort({_id:-1}).hint("FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime").explain('executionStats')

{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "service.Collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "FirstId" : {
                        "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "SecondId" : {
                        "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : -1
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "FirstId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "SecondId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "FirstId" : 1,
                            "SecondId" : 1,
                            "CreationTime" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime",
                        "collation" : {
                            "locale" : "en",
                            "caseLevel" : false,
                            "caseFirst" : "off",
                            "strength" : 1,
                            "numericOrdering" : false,
                            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                            "maxVariable" : "punct",
                            "normalization" : false,
                            "backwards" : false,
                            "version" : "57.1"
                        },
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "FirstId" : [ ],
                            "SecondId" : [ ],
                            "CreationTime" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "FirstId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "SecondId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "CreationTime" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 5491,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 856730,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 856730,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SORT",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 5261,
            "works" : 856734,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 856732,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 6697,
            "restoreState" : 6697,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "sortPattern" : {
                "_id" : -1
            },
            "memUsage" : 432,
            "memLimit" : 33554432,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 5201,
                "works" : 856732,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 856730,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 6697,
                "restoreState" : 6697,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$and" : [
                            {
                                "FirstId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "SecondId" : {
                                    "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 5131,
                    "works" : 856731,
                    "advanced" : 1,
                    "needTime" : 856729,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 6697,
                    "restoreState" : 6697,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 856730,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 856730,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 820,
                        "works" : 856731,
                        "advanced" : 856730,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 6697,
                        "restoreState" : 6697,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "FirstId" : 1,
                            "SecondId" : 1,
                            "CreationTime" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime",
                        "collation" : {
                            "locale" : "en",
                            "caseLevel" : false,
                            "caseFirst" : "off",
                            "strength" : 1,
                            "numericOrdering" : false,
                            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                            "maxVariable" : "punct",
                            "normalization" : false,
                            "backwards" : false,
                            "version" : "57.1"
                        },
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "FirstId" : [ ],
                            "SecondId" : [ ],
                            "CreationTime" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "FirstId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "SecondId" : [
                                "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                            ],
                            "CreationTime" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 856730,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                        "indexDef" : {
                            "indexName" : "FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "FirstId" : [ ],
                                "SecondId" : [ ],
                                "CreationTime" : [ ]
                            },
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "FirstId" : 1,
                                "SecondId" : 1,
                                "CreationTime" : -1
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "direction" : "forward"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but the actual result is a COLLSCAN that takes over 8000ms:

```
 "event": {
  "dataset": "mongodb.log",
  "module": "mongodb"
},
"service": {
  "type": "mongodb"
},
"message": "command service.Collection command: find { find: \"Collection\", 
filter: { FirstId: \"771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349\", SecondId: \"3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f\" }, sort: { CreationTime: -1 }, limit: 1, 
  planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:784787 hasSortStage:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:6175 nreturned:1 reslen:677 
  locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12352 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6176 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 6176 } } } protocol:op_msg 8441ms",
"mongodb.docsExamined": 784787,
"fileset": {
  "name": "log"
},
```

Why am I COLLSCANing instead of IXSCANing with the `FirstIdSecondIDCreationTime` compound index? Is there a way to change my index/ my query to speed up the query?

---

Per a suggestion in the comments, I've run `explain("allPlansExecution")`.

```
///db.Collection.find({ FirstId: "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349", ///SecondId: "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f" })
///   .projection({})
///   .sort({_id:-1}).explain('allPlansExecution')
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "service.Collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "FirstId" : {
                        "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "SecondId" : {
                        "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "FirstId" : {
                            "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "SecondId" : {
                            "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 5408,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 856748,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 856748,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "FirstId" : {
                            "$eq" : "771367b7-4bef-49ab-bda1-6230254c6349"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "SecondId" : {
                            "$eq" : "3bffb3cd-fb5e-43e5-abd1-e0b48c97f78f"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 4862,
            "works" : 856749,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 856747,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 6694,
            "restoreState" : 6694,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 856748,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 856748,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1220,
                "works" : 856749,
                "advanced" : 856748,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 6694,
                "restoreState" : 6694,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 856748,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using explain with `"allPlansExecution"` and no hint to see how the various plans compare.

Comment: To interpret the result of `allPlansExecution`, I guess the winning plan is the filter by the `firstId` and the `secondId` and sort by `_id`? Why is there not a single mention of `FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime`? The plan didn't even run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "FirstIdSecondIdCreationTime" index was not automatically considered because it was created with a collation, and the query is being run without a collation.

Use the [.collation()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.collation/index.html#cursor-collation) cursor method to specify the same collation for the query that was used for the index.

The 5.5 second run time using that index is pretty slow as well.
You may see some improvement in that query if you create an index on `{FirstId: 1, SecondId: 1, _id: 1}` so that they query executor can use the index to meet the sort instead of an in-memory sort.

Comment: ...That worked too well (0ms): [with collation](https://www.protectedtext.com/weguhan). I'm not sure how I'm going to use this information, now that I've done it... 

What do you mean by _so that they query executor can use the index to *meet the sort* instead of an in-memory sort_?

Comment: If the keys in the index are ordered according to equality-sort-range, i.e, the index contains the fields being query as well as the field being sorted, and the fields that the query matches discreet values are before the sort field in the index spec, the query executor can guarantee that scanning the index will find the documents in already sorted order, so it can skip over the in-memory sort stage entirely.  Check out this [blog](https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please sort by leading indexes i.e firstId, secondId and creationTime in the same sequence and see index is used. it will give an idea whether leading indexes fields should be there in sort as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Here are the results for [.sort({FirstId:1, SecondId:1, CreationTime:-1})](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3ka0) and  [.sort({FirstId:1})](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3ka1)