# MongoDB index doing a collection scan instead index scan

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am having a collection with an unique index on name field. This is the output of getIndexes() :

```
{
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1
        },
        "name" : "name_1",
        "ns" : "xxx",
        "sparse" : true,
        "background" : true,
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 2,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        }
    }
```

Now when I do a `.find(name: 'B').explain('executionStats')` , I see in output it does a collection scan instead index scan. Output of `explain('executionStats')` :

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 26,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "name" : {
                    "$eq" : "B"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 28,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 26,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 26
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why it is not using index to scan documents. Note that count 26 in `docExamined` is total number of documents in collection.

Comment: Just as an observation, the explain plan implies you are querying for a name `B`, not `XYZ`.  I would also have expected the index to be used, but sometimes databases will choose to not use any index if the number of records (in this case, Mongo BSON documents) be very small.  26 documents is practically nothing, especially if the JSON you are storing in each document also happens to be small.

Comment: The query had 'B', I have updated the question now. Also i don't think it has to do anything with number of documents. I have observed the same on collections with upto 20K records.

Comment: What percentage of the documents in this collection have a name of `B` ?

Comment: It is a unique index so only 1.

Comment: Something isn't right here.  Can you double check your index definition immediately before running explain?

Comment: I compared the definition before and after running the explain query. One more thing, this collection has few more indexes on other fields. I don't think it would have anything to do here. Could I be wrong?

Comment: More indices just means Mongo would do more work and possibly consider other execution plans.  It does not invalidate the index you did define above.  I expect there is a typo at work here somewhere.

Comment: The collation of the query (i.e. none) doesn't match the collation of the index (provided in the collation option).  See [Why is MongoDB not using the compound index for the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601212/why-is-mongodb-not-using-the-compound-index-for-the-query)

Comment: Yes, ```.find().colation().explain()``` does use index for scan. Thanks for the help. Is there any way to tell mongo to use collation() on collation index automatically, so that I don't have to worry about it.